# Firebase User Specific Data with ReactFire

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I am trying to use ReactFire to get user specific data and display it. I have organized my data in accordance to [Firebase's denormalized suggestions](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html). Here's a look at how the data is structured.

```
"notes" : {
    "n1" : {
        "note" : "[noteData]",
        "created_at" : "[date]",
        "updated_at" : "[date]",
    }
},
"users" : {
    "userOne" : {
    "name" : "[userName]",
        "notes" : {
            "n1" : true
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to get the data reading and writing from my app with the following code without ReactFire, just using the FB API (`updateCode` runs every time a keystroke is typed in the notepad):

```
componentWillMount: function() {
  firebaseRef.child('users/' + authData.uid + '/notes').orderByChild('date_updated').on("child_added", function(noteKeySnapshot) {
  // Take each key and add it to an array
  usersNotesKeys.push(noteKeySnapshot.key());
  // For each note key, go and fetch the Note record with the same key
  firebaseRef.child('notes/' + noteKeySnapshot.key()).once("value", function(noteSnapshot) {
    // Add that full note object to an array + the parent key
    var data = noteSnapshot.val();
    usersNotesList.push({
        'created_at': data.created_at, 
        'updated_at': data.updated_at,
        'note':       data.note,
        'key':        noteKeySnapshot.key()
    });
  });
  this.setState({
    usersNotesList: usersNotesList
  });
}.bind(this)); 
},

updateCode: function(newCode) {
  firebaseRef.child('notes/' + this.state.item['key']).on('value', function(noteSnapshot, prevChildKey) {
  // Look through the current note list and find the matching key and update that key with the new content.

    var data = noteSnapshot.val();
    updatedItem = {
        'created_at': data.created_at, 
        'updated_at': data.updated_at,
        'note':       data.note,
        'key':        noteSnapshot.key()
        };
        // console.log(updatedItem);
    this.setState({
      item: updatedItem
    });
  }.bind(this));
}
```

That code works, technically. But it is sluggishly slow.

When I use ReactFire to write directly to a note, without passing through a  user, it works great and is much simpler. But I need notes to be user specific. So I would like to find a way to use ReactFire with this data structure. Is this possible?

Comment: Why are you pushing to `usersNoteKeys` and `usersNotesList` on `componentWillMount`?

Comment: @arve0 - Great question. `usersNotesList` is the array of the User's notes, once I go and grab them from FB. So that function takes each note and pushes the note data into the `usersNotesList` array, which is then accessible in state.

Comment: Writing data in `componentWillMount` smells fishy. In addition: I don't see any updating of the database happening in `updateCode()`. I do see however that **every time** that `updateCode()` executes, you are attaching a new listener. If `updateCode()` gets called repeatedly, you'll end up with many listeners.

Comment: Thanks, Frank! Just to clarify, there's no writing to the FB database in `componentWillMount`, just to a local array. The DB updating code in `updateCode()` is:

`noteRef.update({ "note": this.state.code, "updated_at": Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP });`

How would you go about updating the code without attaching a new listening in `updateCode()`?

Comment: @dave-dawson Aha, didn't see it defined anywhere. What about removing the event listener in `updateCode` and change the `once` event in `componentWillMount` to a `value` event? Will that not do the same?

Comment: Oh right... I was confused about `usersNotesList.push()`. I don't get outside of the Firebase API much. ;-)

Comment: @arve0 - I'll give that a shot!

Comment: @frankvanPuffelen - But more inline with my original question, is there a way to stick to the Firebase flattened data model using joined tables, while still sticking with ReactFire?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen - Is this something that's possible with ReactFire?

Answer (score 0):

The essential part is that you *do not* want to listen at the full notes tree. This is possible by asserting that notes IDs will not change outside the user's control. A note might be deleted and added by another user and have the same ID, that is fine.

You would start by listening to the current logged in user `user/${auth.id}`, and populate the notes by adding them with `` this.bindAsObject(ref, `note_${noteKeySnapshot.key()}`) ``. Then every time the state updates:

```
 render () {
   let noteKeys = Object.keys(this.state)
   noteKeys = noteKeys.filter(k => k.search('note_') === 0)
   let notes = []
   for (let k in noteKeys) {
     notes.push(this.state[k])
   }
   return <div>
     {notes.map(n => <span>{note.created_at}</span>)}  // and so on
   </div>
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @arve0! Just so I understand, I'm going to be creating an object for each note in the tree, instead of the full `notes` tree itself. Is that right?

Comment: Yes. Just subscribe to the notes you are rendering, the notes belonging to the logged in user. Of course there is some logic missing here, but I'm sure you can find it out. In example, when notes are added/deleted you need to subscribe/unsubscribe.

Comment: Ok, great. This is making so much more sense now! I am able to use `bindAsObject` to set the note objects to state, but they are being set at the top of the state tree (not sure if that's the right term), so they are available at `this.state.[noteObject]`. Is there a way to use ReactFire to add the note object into a `notes` array? It would be great to end up with `this.state.notes.[noteObject].

Comment: Not sure if it's possible to define context in ReactFire. In [re-base](https://github.com/tylermcginnis/re-base) you can. It would go something like this: `base.syncState({context: this.state.notes, state: noteKey })`

Comment: That makes sense conceptually. But I'm getting an error when I try `context: this.state.notes`: "The options argument must contain a context property of type object. Instead, got" Is there another step that's required to add to a state child element?

Comment: Seems like I've misunderstood the `context `option.