# Displaying User Specific Data from Firebase with ReactFire or Re-base

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I am using Firebase as my DB with React on the front-end. I am trying to display user specific data (notes) and display it. I have asked [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34642730/joining-firebase-tables-in-react/) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34731848/firebase-user-specific-data-with-reactfire) on SO, but I think they were too open ended, so this is more specific:

I have organized my data in accordance to [Firebase's denormalized suggestions](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html). Here's a look at how the data is structured:

```
"notes" : {
    "n1" : {
        "note" : "[noteData]",
        "created_at" : "[date]",
        "updated_at" : "[date]",
    }
},
"users" : {
    "userOne" : {
        "name" : "[userName]",
        "notes" : {
            "n1" : true
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks to the other commenters, I have been able to use either [ReactFire](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/react/) and [Tyler McGinnis's Re-base](https://github.com/tylermcginnis/re-base) to grab each user's list of note keys, and create a note object in `state`. This looks like so:

**ReactFire**

```
firebaseRef.child('users/' + authData.uid + '/notes').orderByChild('date_updated').on("child_added", function(noteKeySnapshot) {
    ref = firebaseRef.child('notes/' + noteKeySnapshot.key());
    this.bindAsObject(ref, noteKeySnapshot.key()); 
}.bind(this));
```

**Re-base**

```
firebaseRef.child('users/' + authData.uid + '/notes').orderByChild('date_updated').on("child_added", function(noteKeySnapshot) {
    base.syncState('notes/' + noteKeySnapshot.key(), {
        context: this,
        state: noteKeySnapshot.key(),
        asArray: false,
    });
}.bind(this));
```

Both of these solutions add each note object to the top of the `this.state` tree. This makes it difficult to access the notes as a group. I would like to add each note object to an array, something like `this.state.notes`.

**How can I use either ReactFire or Re-base to add each note object into an array in `this.state`?**

I'm open to other solutions on how these objects can be accessed in `this.state`.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken you have to set it where you putting the snapshot.

in the examples in the Github,

```
componentDidMount(){
  base.syncState(`notes`, {
    context: this,
    state: 'notes', //Changes this to whatever you want as inner state.
    asArray: true
  });
}
```